# How to highlight syntax of Ruby on Google colaboratory?

Tags: ruby, google-colaboratory

I run Ruby code on Google colaboratory. 
https://dev.to/kojix2/ruby-kernel-in-google-colaboratory-32ni

I like Google's colaboratory as it allows us to make use of GPU for free. Ruby can use GPU with [Cumo/NArray](https://github.com/sonots/cumo). Very nice.

But I have one question. In google colaboratory, Ruby code is always gray. The syntax is not highlighted. how to enable syntax highlighting?

Of course, Ruby is not a language officially supported by Google colaboratory. I know it. But If you know something, please tell me!